# python csv2libsvm.py: AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'next'

Tags: python, csv, libsvm

I want to convert a csv file into sparse format file with csv2libsvm.py (https://github.com/zygmuntz/phraug/blob/master/csv2libsvm.py).

The CSV file contains 37 attributes + the label (last column). it doesn't contain header or index.
Exp of the 1st row:     63651000000.0,63651000000.0,153.1,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,1,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1

When entring the following command line : 
    python csv2libsvm.py Z.csv data.txt 38 1

I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csv2libsvm.py", line 47, in <module>
    headers = reader.next()
AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'next'
```

Do you have any idea about the problem ?

Answer (score 92):

This is because of the differences between python 2 and python 3. Use the built-in function `next` in python 3. That is, write `next(reader)` instead of `reader.next()` in line 47. In addition, you should open the file in the text mode. So, change line 47 as `i = open( input_file, 'r' )`.

Comment: So i modified the csv2libsvm.py: 41  i = open( input_file, 'r' )
42   o = open( output_file, 'wb' )

44   reader = csv.reader( i )

46   if skip_headers:
47     headers = next(reader)  but i have the following error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csv2libsvm.py", line 54, in <module>
    label = line.pop( label_index )
IndexError: pop index out of range

Comment: It is another problem! `label_index` should be smaller than the number of elements in each line. Try to investigate the value of `label_index`.

Comment: Yes thank you, i have another error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csv2libsvm.py", line 57, in <module>
    o.write( new_line )
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface                                             So, i modified the  59 line : o.write( bytes(new_line, 'UTF-8') ) , It works but i got a sparse file containing 1 only row that coreesponds to the last row of csv file!!!!

Answer (score 41):

For Python 3.x:

Use `next(reader)` instead of `reader.next()`